# Connected apps deployment troubles in ApiVersion 59.0

Tags: deployment, connected-apps, deployment-error

After changing sourceApiVersion from 58.0 to 59.0 deployment of connected apps started failing with this error:

Property 'isTokenExchangeFlowEnabled' not valid in version 59.0

Error points to this code fragment:

```
<oauthPolicy>
    <ipRelaxation>ENFORCE</ipRelaxation>
    <refreshTokenPolicy>infinite</refreshTokenPolicy>
</oauthPolicy>
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 1):

We have the same issue since last weekend but we still use API 58.0 so I think this is related to the Salesforce Spring '24 release which might be executed last weekend.

I'm still looking into this issue and I will create a ticket at Salesforce and post the updates here.

Feedback from SFDC support:

I have checked thoroughly at the backend and connected with the R&D team to find that this is due to a known issue and multiple customer's have reported this as well.

https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000yEPseAAG/~

The R&D team is checking this on priority and will be updating the known issue as per the confirmation.

I would request you to please Report the Known issue so that you get directly notified on the information by the R&D team.

Comment: Thank you, I will do as you suggest!

Comment: Thank you for your post, same issue here.